# Get object of object value with variable in Pug?

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, pug, object-serialization

I want to use the value of a variable to access an object in Pug.

elem : { Tuteur:{ Name:String, GivenName:String } }

Example:

```
let tmp = "Tuteur.Name",
    tmp_1 = "Tuteur.GivenName";
```

Code Pug:

```
p #{elem[tmp]};
p #{elem[tmp_1]};
```

Comment: `p #{elem.Tuteur.Name}`, `p #{elem.Tuteur.GivenName}`?

Comment: I search with variable,
I know it works p #{elem.Tuteur.Name} !!!!

Comment: I put an example
p #{elem["Tuteur.GivenName"]};

Comment: You're trying to combine dot syntax with bracket syntax, which isn't possible. `elem.Tuteur.Name` is the same as `elem["Tuteur"]["Name"]`, but neither is equivalent to `elem["Tuteur.Name"]`.

Answer (score 0):

As this is not simple code, you're better off doing this in the route and not in the pug template.  Pug templates only handle one-line expressions and this will require a multi-line function.

There is an example contained in the accepted Answer to [this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-with-string-key) that shows how to do this in ten lines of code.

We use the [Sugar Object.get](https://sugarjs.com/docs/#/Object/get) utility function to do this in our application:

Sugar.Object.get(elem, "Tuteur.Name")

There are other JavaScript libraries that will do this, like underscore and lodash.

Finally, it's easier to define expressions like this instead of using interpolation:

```
p= elem.Tuteur.name
```